# how to text-overflow ellipsis none in paragraph by bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to show all without omitting the text in paragraph. How do I do it?

click image ↓

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCwhF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content truncation behavior of the `paragraph` component is governed by the component in which it is nested.

[This part](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/macro-def.content.paragraph) of the documentation will show you how the `paragraph` component behaves with a few components.

A `paragraph` component nested within a `section` component will display the most content.

Comment: In general, any card only shows 2-3 lines (also depend on the font), rest will be ... Section is the only way to guarantee show all content.